# Am using while loop, if_else and try_catch with scanner statement in Java and stuck. Am a beginner and hence confused on finding the error

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, java.util.scanner

Trying to accept input from a user within [0,1,2,3,4] until he enters a valid number. using try-catch to fix the exception error

```
   boolean good = true;
   int x = reader.nextInt();
    while (good != false) {
    try {
        if (x > launchEventList.size()-1) {
            System.out.println("Please provide a valid input");
            reader.nextInt();
        } else {  
            System.out.println("\nDetails of event on index "+ x + " are ==>> " + getLe(x));
            good = false;
        }
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside if statement store the `reader.nextInt()` to variable x.

```
x=reader.nextInt();
```